# "USERAUTH fail" using gradle-ssh-plugin with identity

Tags: ssh, gradle, private-key, gradle-plugin

I can't connect to a SSH host using the [Gradle SSH Plugin](https://gradle-ssh-plugin.github.io/) with my private key.

Specifying the password in the `build.gradle` works fine:

```
remotes {
    webServer {
        host = '<IP>'
        user = '<USER>'
        password = '<PASSWORD>'
    }
}
```

But to avoid writing my password in the build file, I've set my environment to connect using my private key without entering the password from shell:

```
ssh <user>@<ip>
```

This command works from the shell but I can't achieve this with the Gradle plugin. This is my configuration:

```
remotes {
    webServer {
        host = '<IP>'
        user = '<USER>'
        identity = file("${System.getProperty('user.home')}/.ssh/id_rsa")
    }
}
```

The error is:

> Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: USERAUTH fail at com.jcraft.jsch.UserAuthPublicKey.start(UserAuthPublicKey.java:119)

Since I'm able to connect from the shell, what's wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I fixed this by adding the `agent = true` property:

```
remotes {
    webServer {
        host = '54.233.77.171'
        user = 'denis'
        agent = true
        identity = file("${System.getProperty('user.home')}/.ssh/id_rsa")
    }
}
```

> **agent** - If this is set, Putty Agent or ssh-agent will be used on
>   authentication

For more information: [Connections settings](https://gradle-ssh-plugin.github.io/docs/#_set_connection_settings)

I tried this property after analyzing the class [UserAuthPublicKey](https://github.com/rtyley/jsch/blob/master/src/com/jcraft/jsch/UserAuthPublicKey.java):

```
if(userinfo==null) throw new JSchException("USERAUTH fail");
```

Comment: I had the same issue. Just to clarify, the reason this works is because you are using a key with a passphrase. If you happened to be using a passphrase-less private key you wouldn't need the agent for authentication.

Answer (score 3):

I think JCraft only supports PEM keys - when generating the keys, you need to specify the format:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM
```

Comment: If you already have keys and don't want to overwrite them, you can also create a PEM version of the keys: https://gist.github.com/mingfang/4aba327add0807fa5e7f